# CredentialManager with GoogleId always "cancelled"

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, credential-manager

Whichever way I implement compose credential manager, I get an exception
`GetCredentialCancellationException: activity is canceled by the user.`

The manager shows a dialog with my Google accounts, I choose one and then there is a "consent screen" with a "continue as me" button. After clicking that, I get the exception above.

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

My libraries:
`androidx.credentials.credentials:credentials:1.2.0-beta03`
`androidx.credentials.credentials:credentials-play-services-auth:1.2.0-beta03`
`com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.7.0`

The basic demo code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        lifecycleScope.launch {
            CredentialManager.create(this@MainActivity.applicationContext).getCredential(
                context = this@MainActivity,
                request = GetCredentialRequest(
                    listOf(
                        GetGoogleIdOption.Builder()
                            .setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(false)
                            .setAutoSelectEnabled(false)
                            .setServerClientId("secret-id")
                            .build(),
                    )
                ),
            ).credential
        }

        setContent {
            Text("DEMO")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay, finally figured it out after x days. The exception is wrong, it has nothing to do with the problem.

I had wrong client id. It is not supposed to be Android client id, but **WebApplication** client id.

I found it out after checking if google sign in via firebase would work and it was clearly written there, in step 1, point b. https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin#authenticate_with_firebase

Comment: Thank you!! Just to add, the rest of the documentation for android sign in appears to be correct, specifically you don't need the client secret you get from the cloud console, just client id.

Comment: You saved the day! The documentation is really bad...

Comment: Finally worked.

The name was Web client  (auto created by Google Service).